# Unable to save c# TBBS using visual studio

Tags: 2013, templating

I m getting this error while saving c# template using visual studio i m using sdl tridion 2013.i increase the timeout of database query and also maintenance(updating index and shrinking files) has done on sql database

> Unable to save (test 'tcm:1017-2074-2048'). The
>   transaction associated with the current connection has completed but
>   has not been disposed. The transaction must be disposed before the
>   connection can be used to execute SQL statements. Component:
>   Templating Errorcode: 2049 User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
>   StackTrace Information Details: at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteRPC(_SqlRPC[] rpcArray,
>   Int32 timeout, Boolean inSchema, SqlNotificationRequest
>   notificationRequest, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean
>   isCommandProc, Boolean sync, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32
>   startRpc, Int32 startParam) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean asyncWrite) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseUtilities.ExecuteNonQuery(StoredProcedureInvocation
>   storedProcedureInvocation) at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.ExecuteNonQuery(StoredProcedureInvocation
>   storedProcedureInvocation) at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.ContentManagement.VersionedItemDataMapper.Tridion.ContentManager.Data.ContentManagement.IVersionedItemDataMapper.RevisionApplicationData(TcmUri
>   target) at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.OnCheckedIn(CheckInEventArgs
>   eventArgs) at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.CheckIn(Boolean
>   removePermanentLock, Boolean fromWorkflow, String userComment) at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.Save(Boolean
>   checkInAfterSave) at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.DotNetTemplate.Save() at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.DotNetTemplate.Save() at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.TemplateAssemblyStorage.StoreTemplateAssembly(Byte[]
>   assemblyContents, Byte[] pdbContents, String assemblyFileName, String
>   targetFolder, String associateBundle) at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.TemplateAssemblyStorage.PerformStoreTemplateAssembly(Session
>   session, Byte[] assemblyContents, Byte[] pdbContents, String
>   assemblyFileName, String targetFolder, String associateBundle

Comment: You mention updating indexes and shrinking files, but did you update the statistics and truncate the transaction log of the database? (I can see it is a heavily used system since you are already at Publication ID 1017). Also are you only having problems uploading the TBB via Visual Studio, does it work if you use `TcmUploadAssembly` via the command line, or can you create an Assembly TBB manually and upload the assembly via the CME?

Answer (score 6):

Problem is solved .problem was because of we migrate cms database from one server to other server and in QUEUE_CONSUMERS table the old Host was still online after changing it to offline  i m able to update TBB.