# CoreService timeout error : The transaction associated with the current connection has completed but has not been disposed.

Tags: core-service

I was able to create a new publication with test data using the CoreService and PowerShell.

The second attempt results in a timeout error. Even after rebooting the virtual server. It is a development environment with a clean Tridion install.

Windows Server 2012 R2 + SQL Server 2012 SP1 + SDL Tridion 2013 SP1

There is another post related to this message but change the config doesnt solve the problem.

Error message:

```
The transaction associated with the current connection has completed but has not been disposed.  The transaction must be disposed before the connection can be used to execute SQL statements.
Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService Errorcode: 0 User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE  StackTrace Information Details:
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteRPC(_SqlRPC[] rpcArray, Int32 timeout, Boolean inSchema, SqlNotificationRequest notificationRequest, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isCommandProc, Boolean sync, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 startRpc, Int32 startParam)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.DeriveParameters()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(SqlCommand command)
at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.GetParametersFromStoredProcedure(String storedProcedureName)
at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.GetStoredProcedureCommand(StoredProcedureInvocation storedProcedureInvocation)
at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseUtilities.ExecuteReader(StoredProcedureInvocation storedProcedureInvocation, CommandBehavior commandBehavior)
at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.ExecuteReader(StoredProcedureInvocation storedProcedureInvocation, CommandBehavior commandBehavior)
at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseUtilities.ExecuteReader(StoredProcedureInvocation storedProcedureInvocation)
at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.ExecuteReader(StoredProcedureInvocation storedProcedureInvocation)
at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.ContentManagement.RepositoryDataMapper.Tridion.ContentManager.Data.ContentManagement.IRepositoryDataMapper.GetListItems(TcmUri id, RepositoryItemsFilterData filterData)
at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Repository.GenerateAndUpdateCategoriesXsd(TcmUri id, Session currentSession)
at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Repository.GenerateAndUpdateCategoriesXsd()
at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Repository.OnLoaded(LoadEventArgs eventArgs)
at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Load(LoadFlags flags, Boolean forceReload)
at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Reload()
at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Repository.OnSaved(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
at Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Publication.OnSaved(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save()
at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceBase.Create(IdentifiableObjectData data, ReadOptions readBackOptions)
at SyncInvokeCreate(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Comment: what did you change in the config? timeout?

Answer (score 1):

1. Did you applied both the methods given in the knowledge base article: [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861)
2. Also make sure that distributed transactions are allowed on SQL server - MSTDC, you can try uninstalling and reinstalling MSTDC. Some people have got success by doing so.
3. Try disabling firewall between the servers (CMS and SQL)

I have similar configurations on Azure and have succeeded by applying above steps. I did a clean installation of Tridion and observed errors like this and also of External Library under Event viewer. After performing these mentioned steps everything is working perfect.

Comment: The setup runs on my VM on my laptop, so firewall is not an issue. It did work once, creating a Publication via the CoreService with some PowerShell commands. The next attempt failed however. The link you have provided does not relate to my setup.

Answer (score 1):

I would try following :-

1. DB Performance improvement

   - EXECUTE sys.sp_updatestats,
   - Update the indices
   - run Clean up publication path script  (check with SDL for this script)- i once  run it on old CMS version for performance improvement.
2. Change Time out setting in Tridion CM configuration
3. Increase msdtc timeout
4. [Unable to save c# TBBS using visual studio](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4511/unable-to-save-c-tbbs-using-visual-studio)

Comment: My setup is a clean install of SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 on Windows Server 2012 R2 with SQL Server 2012 SP1. The Tridion_cm database is empty except for one publication which I could create with a PowerShell script. The link you provided talks about queue_consumers table which is dirty, but in my case the queue_consumers only contain my server.